# Tile change color on mouse hover - prevent selecting more than one tile at once

Tags: java, graphics

I am creating a battle ship game, where each round the player can select 4 ship routes by selecting the 4 closest tiles to him, with a mouse.

Now in the following gif, you can see if I will hover on the very edge of a tile, it will select two tiles at once, or even 4 at once if you're holding your mouse in middle of 4 tiles:

[image: gif]
<sub>(source: [gyazo.com](http://gyazo.com/4d9f4a07b19d01642f92d3818f36b5fa.gif))</sub>

This should not really be happening in the game, how can I prevent that?

This is the updating code:

```
/**
 * 
 * @param x mouse X
 * @param y mouse Y 
 */
public void checkHover(int x, int y) {
    for (int i = 0; i < tiles[0].length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < tiles[1].length; j++) {

            // get coordinates from tile
            int x1 = i * (sprite.getWidth() - 1);
            int y1 = j * (sprite.getHeight() - 1);  

            // If we have screen translate, we can cancel it for 
            // this situation
            int realX = x - this.translate.getX();
            int realY = y - this.translate.getY();

            // checking if mouse inside tile
            if (realX >= x1 && realX <= x1 + sprite.getWidth() &&
                    realY >= y1 && realY <= y1 + sprite.getHeight()) {
                // set tile to hovered sprite
                this.tiles[i][j].setHover(true);
            }
            else {
                // cancel hovered sprite
                this.tiles[i][j].setHover(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can I prevent that?

Comment: Breaking the loop is one solution (so when you get a positive hit you could break out of the loop), but to could be keeping previously highlighted cells active. You could reduce your hit check using "< x1 + sprite.getWidth()" instead. Another solution would be to simply calculate the tile at the mouse position directly, keeping a reference to the tile as the selected tile, but this would change the way it's painted. You could also take advantage of the 2D graphics API to calculate positive hits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of the two loops I would calculate the index of the 2d array based off the x and y position of the mouse, by dividing the x and y position by how much space there is from one tile to the next (which looks to be the tile width plus 1, the empty border). This will cause border hovers to favor a certain side, but it looks like you don't want to select two tiles anyways.

Once you have the index of the tile, switch the highlight on, and keep a reference to it with an instance variable like `lastHighlightedTile`, but before you do that, also call `lastHighlightedTile.setHover(false);`.

If the index of the tile is invalid, as if the mouse is out of the tile area, don't access the array and still call `lastHighlightedTile.setHover(false);`.

This should fix highlighting multiple tiles, and will also allow you to turn off the previous highlight (the solution of breaking out of the current loop might not turn off the previous highlight).

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Different solution:
Simply declare a boolean at the beginning of the method, and set only if that boolean is still false. Once you set the tile on, also set the boolean to true, which will prevent others from being set on.

```
public void checkHover(int x, int y) {
   boolean hasTurnedOneOn = false;
   for (int i = 0; i < tiles[0].length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < tiles[1].length; j++) {

        // get coordinates from tile
        int x1 = i * (sprite.getWidth() - 1);
        int y1 = j * (sprite.getHeight() - 1);  

        // If we have screen translate, we can cancel it for 
        // this situation
        int realX = x - this.translate.getX();
        int realY = y - this.translate.getY();

        // checking if mouse inside tile
        if (realX >= x1 && realX <= x1 + sprite.getWidth() &&
                realY >= y1 && realY <= y1 + sprite.getHeight() && !hasTurnedOneOn) {
            // set tile to hovered sprite
            this.tiles[i][j].setHover(true);
            hasTurnedOneOn = true;
        }
        else {
            // cancel hovered sprite
            this.tiles[i][j].setHover(false);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Seriously, don't use labels. There must be 101 better ways to achieve the same result :P

Comment: Breaking early out of the loop might not turn off the previous highlight, unless Ben Beri has more logic to do that.

Comment: @MadProgrammer found another way :)

Comment: @NESPowerGlove You're correct. I'd appreciate if you take a look at my new way - will that work?

Comment: It's a better approach then before, it should work...haven't tested it though ;)

Comment: @DeanLeitersdorf The edit seems like it would work, but it would be nice to avoid the O(N) overhead of the method if possible. I find that usually in games you only need to have a full O(N) loop over all entities once or twice, to update and draw each one individually, while all other situations (like collision detection) can use other means to narrow down what entities to look at.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming width of sprite is equal to 50, I see that first title has x1 to x2 coordinate (0 - 50), second title has (49 - 100), third has (99 - 150)... Same for y dimension.

So when pointer is at (x) = (50), it hovers (x1 - x2) (0-50) and (49-100) titles.

Why are you subtracting 1 from sprite width / height?
try with this:

```
        // get coordinates from tile
        int x1 = i * (sprite.getWidth());
        int y1 = j * (sprite.getHeight());
```

Edit: I wrote sample app, which shoved me solution:

```
public class App {

Tile[][] tiles;
Sprite sprite;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    App app = new App();
    app.init();
    app.checkHover(50, 50);
    app.printHovers();
}

private void init() {
    sprite = new Sprite();
    tiles = new Tile[10][10];
    for (int i = 0; i < tiles[0].length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < tiles[1].length; j++) {
            tiles[i][j] = new Tile();
        }
    }
}

public void checkHover(int x, int y) {
    for (int i = 0; i < tiles[0].length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < tiles[i].length; j++) {

            // get coordinates from tile
            int x1 = i * (sprite.getWidth());
            int y1 = j * (sprite.getHeight());

            // If we have screen translate, we can cancel it for
            // this situation
            // int realX = x - this.translate.getX();
            // int realY = y - this.translate.getY();
            int realX = x;
            int realY = y;

            // checking if mouse inside tile
            if (realX >= x1 && realX < x1 + sprite.getWidth()
                    && realY >= y1 && realY < y1 + sprite.getHeight()) {
                // set tile to hovered sprite
                this.tiles[i][j].setHover(true);
            } else {
                // cancel hovered sprite
                this.tiles[i][j].setHover(false);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void printHovers() {
    for (int i = 0; i < tiles[0].length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < tiles[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print((tiles[i][j].isHover() ? "Y" : "O") + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

public class Sprite {

    public int getWidth() {
        return 50;
    }

    public int getHeight() {
        return 50;
    }
}

public class Tile {

    private boolean hover;

    public boolean isHover() {
        return hover;
    }

    public void setHover(boolean hover) {
        this.hover = hover;
    }
}
}
```

It works fine for (49, 49), (49, 50), (50, 49) and (50, 50) coords.
So, first you have to remove -1 subtractions, and change `<=` test to `<`.

Comment: My only concern would be ensuring that no other titles are still selected, but we don't exactly have a lot of code to go on...

Comment: @MGordon Because I need to move them 1px off, to make the nice sharp borders.